# How can I check if variable contains Chinese/Japanese characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I check if a variable contains Chinese or Japanese characters? I know that this line works:

```
if (document.body.innerText.match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/))
```

I need to do the same thing not for the document but for a single variable.

Comment: `if (variable.match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/))` ?

Comment: You can apply `.match` to *any* string variable, not just `document.body.innerText`.

Comment: Thank you. What I'm trying to do is to have the user select a portion of text from the document and assign it to my variable and after this check if the variable contains any Chinese character. I'm using var sel = window.getSelection() and then if (sel.match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/)) but it won't work. Strange thing is that if e.g I manually set sel = 漢字 it works fine but if I try to get it with window.getSelection() it won't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.match` is a string method. You can apply it to anything that contains string. And, of course, to arbitrary variable.

In case you have something that is not string, most objects define `.toString()` method that converts its content to some reasonable stringified form. When you retrieve selection from page, you get selection object. Convert it to string and then use `match` on it: `sel.toString().match(...)`.

Comment: Thank you. What I'm trying to do is to have the user select a portion of text from the document and assign it to my variable and after this check if the variable contains any Chinese character. I'm using var sel = window.getSelection() and then if (sel.match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/)) but it won't work. Strange thing is that if e.g I manually set sel = 漢字  it works fine but if I try to get it with window.getSelection() it won't.

Comment: That's because it returns selection object, that must be first converted to string. Use `sel.toString().match(...)`.

Comment: `/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/.test( window.getSelection().toString() )` would be better: it only has to return a Boolean rather than an array of matches.

Answer (score 0):

afaik you can to the same with a variable... `document.body.innerText` just returns the text of the body. Therefore you can just do

```
myvar.match(...)
```

Here's an example: http://snipplr.com/view/15357/

Comment: Thank you. What I'm trying to do is to have the user select a portion of text from the document and assign it to my variable and after this check if the variable contains any Chinese character. I'm using var sel = window.getSelection() and then if (sel.match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/)) but it won't work. Strange thing is that if e.g I manually set sel = 漢字  it works fine but if I try to get it with window.getSelection() it won't.

Comment: try `sel.toString().match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/))`