# Using JavaScript to check whether a string contains Japanese characters (including kanji)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, kana

How can I check whether a given string contains one or more Japanese characters (consisting of kana and/or kanji)?

I saw a similar question here: [How can I check if variable contains Chinese/Japanese characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206443/how-can-i-check-if-variable-contains-chinese-japanese-characters) , and I used the solution to come up with this:

```
var containsJapanese = string.match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/);
```

However, this gives many false positives.

I've tested it by having a script iterate through the contents of entire web pages-- such as Facebook, Stack Overflow, etc.-- and marking the divs which supposedly contain Japanese text.  In those cases, a large number of divs end up getting marked by mistake.  I've also tested it on pages that *do* contain Japanese text, and the Japanese divs there end up getting marked correctly alongside many incorrectly-marked divs.

Comment: string.match gives string comparison only and not UTF comparison

Comment: @user1428716: That is regex being put in there, so it will detect the characters within the range. However, whether it is correct Japanese or not is another matter...

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Check whether this works or not. I found [this website](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml) that seems to list all the characters in Unicode that might be used in Japanese text.

The corresponding regex (for single character) would be:

```
/[\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf]/
  -------------_____________-------------_____________-------------_____________
   Punctuation   Hiragana     Katakana    Full-width       CJK      CJK Ext. A
                                            Roman/      (Common &      (Rare)    
                                          Half-width    Uncommon)
                                           Katakana
```

The ranges are (as quoted from the site):

- `3000 - 303f`: Japanese-style punctuation
- `3040 - 309f`: Hiragana
- `30a0 - 30ff`: Katakana
- `ff00 - ff9f`: Full-width Roman characters and half-width Katakana
- `4e00 - 9faf`: CJK unified ideographs - Common and uncommon Kanji
- `3400 - 4dbf`: CJK unified ideographs Extension A - Rare Kanji

I have changed the ranges a bit:

- I have changed from `ff00 - ffef` to `ff00 - ff9f` for *Full-width Roman characters and half-width Katakana*. The code points from `ffa0 - ffdc` contains Hangul half-width characters, which is not what you want. You may want to re-add the code points from `ffe0 - ffef`, but they are mostly half-width punctuations or full-width currency symbols.

You can check the site and take off any range you don't want, or are sure that it will not appear in your input.

Answer (score -1):

Use charCode function to detect japanese language. For example, 
  (from website http://www.jpf.go.jp/j/index.html)

```
 var a=$('a[href$="culture/new/index.html"]').text();
  a=a+'K';
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){ //3 as i knew it was length 3. Please use string.length
    console.log(a.charCodeAt(i));
   //Detect the charCode here and use break on match
 }


 Output : 19968 35239 75
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but can you be more specific as to which character code values to compare against?

Comment: [This link](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml) has UNICODE in HEX - you have to check for DECIMAL values. Use : http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

Answer (score -2):

check hiragana full size
/^[ぁ-ん]+$/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).