# RegEx : Check any special characters in String

Tags: .net, regex, c++-cli

How to check a string that contains special characters such as `_ . , ( ) & ^ % $ # @ ! *` in my string?
 I tried to create a regular expression validator for checking the string as follows.

```
bool isOk = Regex::IsMatch(firstname, "^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

This is the name field in registration form. It should allow Japanese characters. But with my RegEx only allow English characters. I know this is because `[a-zA-Z]`. But how to check only the special characters and leave Japanese or Korean characters?

Comment: This may be helpful http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change RegEx to allow for both English & Japanese characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151230/change-regex-to-allow-for-both-english-japanese-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably have a better idea of what you don't want to allow than what you do want to allow, use an inverted set of characters using the [^ ] syntax.

```
bool isOk = Regex::IsMatch(firstname, "^[^_\\.,\\(\\)&^%$#@!\\*]+$");
```

But please note that in English ['FULL STOP' (U+002E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002e/index.htm) is sometimes used in names. Your blacklist approach would prohibit them. So, consider removing it from the code above.

Also, ['SPACE' (U+0020)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm) and ['HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) are used in names in English. Your whitelist approach would prohibit them.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found some examples of RegExp expressions for Unicode characters:

Regex for matching ALL Japanese common & uncommon Kanji

```
`(4e00 – 9fcf)`
```

~ The Big Kahuna!

```
([一-龯])
```

Regex for matching Hirgana or Katakana

```
([ぁ-んァ-ン])
```

and many more...

regex-japanese.txt from terrancesnyder  on GitHubGist: https://gist.github.com/terrancesnyder/1345094

One more good reply: [Regular expressions (regex) in Japanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809176/regular-expressions-regex-in-japanese)