# regex python with unicode (japanese) character issue

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I want to remove part of a string (shown in bold) below, this is stored in the string *oldString*

[DMSM-8433] **加護亜依** Kago Ai – 加護亜依 vs. FRIDAY

im using the following regex within python

```
p=re.compile(ur"( [\W]+) (?=[A-Za-z ]+–)", re.UNICODE)
newString=p.sub("", oldString)
```

when i output the *newString* nothing has been removed

Comment: `oldString` should also be converted to Unicode. Is it? How do you obtain it? Try `oldString = unicode(oldString, "utf-8")` before declaring `p`.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @stribizhev i specify `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file, from what i've been reading this should convert it to unicode, I obtain it from scraping a HTML page
@Kasramvd expected output should be "[DMSM-8433] Kago Ai – 加護亜依 vs. FRIDAY"

Comment: Try this [snippet](https://ideone.com/fN74qX).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033196/using-javascript-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-japanese-characters-includi/15034560#15034560

Comment: @stribizhev that seems to work like a charm, thanks for that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following snippet to solve the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
str = u'[DMSM-8433] 加護亜依 Kago Ai – 加護亜依 vs. FRIDAY'
regex = u'[\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf]+ (?=[A-Za-z ]+–)'
p = re.compile(regex, re.U)
match = p.sub("", str)
print match.encode("UTF-8")
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/fN74qX)

Beside `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` declaration, I have added [@nhahtdh's character class to detect Japanese symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033196/using-javascript-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-japanese-characters-includi/15034560#15034560).

Note that the `match`  needs to be encoded as UTF-8 string "manually" since Python 2 needs to be "reminded" we are working with Unicode all the time.

Comment: Just a note: on Windows, in Python 2.x, the `# coding: utf-8` instruction can be added to enforce UTF8 encoding for the source.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a regular expression like this one:

```
([\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}\p{Han}]+)
```

please refer also to [this documentation.](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/)

EDIT:
I also tested it [here](https://regex101.com/r/oE0oL5/1).

Comment: Python re doesn't support Unicode properties. Of course, there is [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package, but you need to mention it in the answer. (Also, I'm not quite sure whether the syntax above would be accepted in regex package)

Comment: that seems to work with PHP but not with Python, when running through Python is strips "Kag" and "i" from "Kago Ai"

Comment: @nhahtdh using re package at the moment, didnt realise there was another, I'll have a read through the link

Comment: [Test it with proper settings](https://regex101.com/r/oE0oL5/3). Results are very different.

Comment: I agree with you @stribizhev