# Custom word tokenizer

Tags: python, regex, tokenize, tweepy

I'm analyzing twitter data for sentiment analysis, and I need to tokenize tweets for my analysis.

Let this be an example tweet:

`tweet = "Barça, que más veces ha jugado contra 10 en la historia https://twitter.com/7WUjZrMJah #UCL"`

The `nltk.word_tokenize()` tokenizes the tweets alright but breaks at links and hashtags.

```
word_tokenize(tweet)

>>> ['Bar\xc3\xa7a', ',', 'que', 'm\xc3\xa1s', 'veces', 'ha', 'jugado', 'contra', '10', 'en', 'la', 'historia', 'https', ':', '//twitter.com/7WUjZrMJah', '#', 'UCL']`
```

The unicode characters remain intact, but links are broken. I have designed a custom regex tokenizer, which is:

```
emoticons = r'(?:[:;=\^\-oO][\-_\.]?[\)\(\]\[\-DPOp_\^\\\/])'

regex_tweets = [
    emoticons,
    r'<[^>]+>',      ## HTML TAGS
    r'(?:@[\w\d_]+)',   ## @-mentions
    r'(?:\#[\w]+)',  ## #HashTags
    r'http[s]?://(?:[a-z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]))+', # URLs
    r"(?:[a-z][a-z'\-_]+[a-z])", # words with - and '
    r'(?:(?:\d+,?)+(?:\.?\d+)?)',  ##numbers
    r'(?:[\w_]+)',   #other words
    r'(?:\S)'        ## normal text 
]

#compiling regex
tokens_re = re.compile(r'('+'|'.join(regex_tweets)+')' ,re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
tokens_re.findall(string)

>>> ['Bar', '\xc3', '\xa7', 'a', ',', 'que', 'm', '\xc3', '\xa1', 's', 'veces', 'ha', 'jugado', 'contra', '10', 'en', 'la', 'historia', 'https://twitter.com/7WUjZrMJah', '#UCL']
```

Now the hashtags and links appear the way I want them to, but breaks at unicode charachters (like Barça -> `['Bar', '\xc3', '\xa7', 'a']` instead of  `['Bar\xc3\xa7a']`

*Is there any way I can **integrate both of these**??
Or a regular expression that includes unicode characters??*

I have also tried `TweetTokenizer` from the `nltk.tokenize` library, but it wasn't very useful.

Comment: You need to also specify the `re.U` flag. `re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE | re.UNICODE`. Also note that `[\w\d_]+` = `\w+`. Also, this `(?:(?:\d+,?)+(?:\.?\d+)?)` looks fragile.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew did that, but nothing changed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll go through the regular expressions again later to optimise them and make them more robust, the regular expressions are working fine for now, I need to catch the unicode words.

Comment: Is it Python 2.7? Are you encoding the input texts as UTF8?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, it's python 2.7. and I have added `# coding=utf-8` at the top if that's what you meant...

Comment: No, something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863608/regex-python-with-unicode-japanese-character-issue/32868484#32868484).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't do that, now it seems to be working the way I desired it to. Its still breaking at a few characters, but it's better than before! Thanks!

Comment: You can post your solution BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out most of the unicode characters don't break if I declare the string as a unicode string. It still breaks at many words, but the performance is better.

```
# coding=utf-8

tweet = u"Barça, que más veces ha jugado contra 10 en la historia https://twitter.com/7WUjZrMJah #UCL"

emoticons = r'(?:[:;=\^\-oO][\-_\.]?[\)\(\]\[\-DPOp_\^\\\/])'

regex_tweets = [
    emoticons,
    r'<[^>]+>',      ## HTML TAGS
    r'(?:@[\w\d_]+)',   ## @-mentions
    r'(?:\#[\w]+)',  ## #HashTags
    r'http[s]?://(?:[a-z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]))+', # URLs
    r"(?:[a-z][a-z'\-_]+[a-z])", # words with - and '
    r'(?:(?:\d+,?)+(?:\.?\d+)?)',  ##numbers
    r'(?:[\w_]+)',   #other words
    r'(?:\S)'        ## normal text 
]

#compiling regex
tokens_re = re.compile(r'('+'|'.join(regex_tweets)+')' ,re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
tokens_re.findall(string)

>>>[u'Bar', u'\xe7a', u',', u'que', u'm\xe1s', u'veces', u'ha', u'jugado', u'contra', u'10', u'en', u'la', u'historia', u'https://twitter.com/7WUjZrMJah', u'#UCL']
```

It still tokenised `Barça` to `[u'Bar', u'\xe7a']`, which is better than  `['Bar', '\xc3', '\xa7', 'a']`, but still not the original term `['Bar\xc3\xa7a']`. But it does work on many expressions.