# Regex in JavaScript to match writing systems without word boundaries

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I'm trying to detect in a text if there are characters belonging to the [writing system of a language without word boundaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Writing_systems_without_word_boundaries).
These writing systems are the following according to Wikipedia (I have added the ISO 639-2 or 639-3 code)

```
Burmese  MY
Chinese ZH
Japanese JA
S'gaw Karen KAR
Khmer KM
Lao LP
ʼPhags-pa PHAG
Pwo Karen PWO
S'gaw Karen KAR
Tai Tham LANA
Thai TH
Tibetan BO
```

In the case of `Chinese` I'm using a specific regex for `Han` writing system:

```
HAN_REGEX = /[\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u3005\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303B\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9]/;
```

as an equivalent to `\p{Han}`. An alternative solution for Chinese hieroglyphs is to use directly

```
let regexp = /\p{sc=Han}/gu;
```

So let's say given the `Kanji` Unicode Table,  the charset range to detect `JA` in the text is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033196/using-javascript-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-japanese-characters-includi):

```
KANJI_REGEX = /[\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf]/
```

but what about the other writing systems? Is the [charset range](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=3584&number=128&utf8=0x) the only way?

Comment: @SamuelLiew The OP lists 12 writing systems that share a common structure and are different from other writing systems. OP has shown that they know how to recognize each of the 12 independently, and are asking if there is a single regex that works for all, without having to specify the charset range for each one. I think the question is sufficiently focused, and am voting to reopen. Can you take another look please?

Comment: It works, I see that it has been reopened now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't take care of all of the cases because I can't seem to get a good reference for how to recognize scriptio continua, but it should get you mostly there.

```
let regex = new RegExp(/[\p{Script_Extensions=Mymr}\p{Script_Extensions=Han}\p{Script_Extensions=Hira}\p{Script_Extensions=Kana}\p{Script_Extensions=Bopo}\p{Script=Khmer}\p{Script=Lao}\p{Script_Extensions=Phag}\p{Script=Tai_Tham}\p{Script=Thai}\p{Script=Tibetan}]/u)
```

Script_Extensions will include all of the extended characters of a script in addition to the base, so you're usually better off using Script_Extensions when you can.

- \p{Script_Extensions=Mymr} should match any characters from the Myanmar script (which is what the Burmese, S'gaw Karen, and Pwo Karen seem to be mapped to)
- \p{Script_Extensions=Han} should match Han or Kanji characters
- \p{Script_Extensions=Bopo} should match Bopomofo characters (since Hanb is Han+Bopo but unicode doesn't have a combination script, this should match the other Chinese characters)
- \p{Script_Extensions=Hira} should match any Hiragana characters
- \p{Script_Extensions=Kana} should match any Katakana characters
- \p{Script=Khmer} should match characters in Khmer script
- \p{Script=Lao} should match characters in Lao script
- \p{Script_Extensions=Phag} should match characters in 'Phags-pa script
- \p{Script=Tai_Tham} should match characters in Tai Tham script
- \p{Script=Thai} should match characters in Thai script
- \p{Script=Tibetan} should match characters in Tibetan script

And since unicode property escapes can't be used without the unicode flag set, it's important to remember to pass the 'u' flag.